# Having error with NSArray

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

Im having this error:

> 2013-05-30 21:07:05.330 SADD[5785:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key descriptionLabel.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1c95012 0x10d2e7e 0x1d1dfb1 0xb7ee41 0xb005f8 0xb000e7 0xb2ab58 0x234019 0x10e6663 0x1c9045a 0x232b1c 0x2348da 0x3758 0xd18fb 0xd19cf 0xba1bb 0xcab4b 0x672dd 0x10e66b0 0x2291fc0 0x228633c 0x2286150 0x22040bc 0x2205227 0x22058e2 0x1c5dafe 0x1c5da3d 0x1c3b7c2 0x1c3af44 0x1c3ae1b 0x1bef7e3 0x1bef668 0x16ffc 0x299d 0x28c5)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   (lldb)

My code can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/fD8twua5

The error occurs when I press the "events" button on XYZVIEWCONTROLLER page.

The error seems to come from this line of code in EVENTSVIEWCONTROLLER.m:

```
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
```

My code can be download at: [CODE DOWNLOAD](http://www.mediafire.com/download/apykivr5oay5hay/SADD.zip)

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: check the owner of the `SimpleTableCell`

Comment: Would it be possible to help me by looking at the entire project? Thanks so much! mediafire.com/download/apykivr5oay5hay/SADD.zip

Comment: Presumably "SimpleTableCell.xib" names SomeClass (Please observe standard Objective-C naming conventions in the future) as its owner.  But SomeClass does not define "descriptionLabel" (or defines it improperly).

Comment: Sorry if its a noob question, but how can I define it?

Comment: Or maybe the problem is right here: `owner:self`

Comment: What should i change owner:self to?

Comment: The owner is presumably a SimpleTableCell object.

Comment: Sorry but what should I change it to then?

Comment: You are loading a "NIB" that expects to find a "descriptionLabel" IBOutlet in its owner.  The only class you have that defines that is SimpleTableCell, so I suppose you need one of those.  It kinda looks like you have one a few lines earlier in your code.  (Though the more I look at your code the less sense it makes.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem in your nib file. You have an element in your nib searchig for the descriptionLabel in your viewcontroller, and probably you do not have a descriptonLabel declared in the viewcontroller corresponding to the nib.

-

To can help you directly in your code It is needed to check your nib file, check the class and also the outlets that are connected to it.

-

**EDIT**

Looking at your code I see that you want to load a table view cell from a nib, what is not a standar from apple, to do that you need to do a workaround, the problem loading the way you are showing to us, is that it will load it to your EVENTSViewController, and in this ViewController you do not have the Outlets that the nib is trying to load, to workaround it you will need to:

First you will need to change the owner of the nib, must be your EVENTSViewController, that need to have the outlet tableViewCell.

Can look something like that:

```
@implementation EVENTSViewController
{
    NSArray *tableData;
    NSArray *descriptionData;
    __weak IBOutlet UITableViewCell* tableViewCell;
}
```

Or you can create a property, this is your choice.

At your nib file you will need to change name and the description to the cell outlet, you can drag it to the cell, not to the file owner, and then it will work.

You can get your working code here: https://mega.co.nz/#!gAtC1bIA!JBBeTDConxibiNfCN9_z-WVy12w6FxPtiDwBm3s_818

Comment: I can't find where in my code descriptionLabel is missing... you can download my code here, would it be possible to help me by looking at the entire project? Thanks so much! http://www.mediafire.com/download/apykivr5oay5hay/SADD.zip

Comment: @MatthewBrand - You can't find where it's not defined because it's not defined.

Comment: Sorry if its a noob question, but how can I define it?

Comment: hmm, to load a cell from the nib you need to do a workaround, I will post how you can do that, just a second.

Comment: Thanks! Cant wait to fix this problem!